# Getting List data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>List Manipulation</title>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("ul li").click(function(){
               var s;// in this variable i want "list item 1"
               window.alert(s);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I have written a simple html code which has unordered list. When I click on elements in this list, i want the content of the list element that was clicked. I have commented it in the code.
I have tried

```
var s = this.text;//giving undefined value

var s = this.value ;// giving 0
```

Comment: var s = $(this).text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
var s = $(this).text();
```